# Cannot access internet with Ubuntu 19 in VirtualBox?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, dns

Hi I installed Ubuntu virtual machine with my company computer, my platform are listed as follow:

```
Host OS:             Windows 10
Host Firewall:       Mcafee(Company security requirement)
Virtual OS:          Ubuntu 19.10
Virtualization Soft: VirtualBox
Network mode:        NAT
```

I can actually ping DNS and outside web address(such as archive.ubuntu.com or www.baidu.com), but with no internet access. Neither from browser nor from other softwares(such as apt).

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: You should consider changing your VirtualBox virtual adapter to `Bridged` mode and troubleshoot from there.

Comment: Hi I've changed from NAT to bridge, but same thing. All pings worked, but no internet. Can I have further more info @Anaksunaman? Thank you!

Comment: [These are a couple basic solutions to try in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/717029/285608).

Comment: Hi it seems not working, the internet icon in the top right corner still showing a question mark.......